# Switching activity when MediaRecorder reaches maximum duration

Tags: android, uinavigationbar, android-mediarecorder

I am implementing MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener to Switch an activity, but the method argument is not accepting View parameter! What should I do?

Here is the source code.

```
@Override
public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if( what == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED)
    {
         stopRecording(View);//View cannot be resolved to variable
    }
}
```

here is stopRecoring for switching another activity...

```
    public void stopRecording(View v) {
    Log.d(TAG, "stopRecording()");
    assert this.mediaRecorder != null;
    try {
        this.mediaRecorder.stop();
        timeSwapBuff += timeInMilliseconds;
         customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.saved, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // we are no longer recording
        flipCamera.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        captureImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        this.toggleButtons(false);
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        // the recording did not succeed
        Log.w(TAG, "Failed to record", e);
        if (this.file != null && this.file.exists() && this.file.delete()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Deleted " + this.file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        return;
    } finally {
        this.releaseMediaRecorder();
    }
    if (this.file == null || !this.file.exists()) {
        Log.w(TAG,
                "File does not exist after stop: "
                        + this.file.getAbsolutePath());
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG,
                "Going to display the video: "
                        + this.file.getAbsolutePath());
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, VideoPlaybackActivity.class);
        intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
        System.out.println("########Uri is: " + Uri.fromFile(file));
        intent.putExtra("fromClass", "");
        intent.putExtra("file_name", videoName); 
        super.startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Well, where does the `View` you're passing come from?

Comment: so what should i pass? @ChiefTwoPencils

Comment: what You are doing with the View, can´t see that You are using it? please show the part of Your code where You set the mediaRecorder onInfoListener. Is it possible that You use a View that You named "View"?

Comment: I have no idea. You've shown a method who's scope does not show any variable `View`, which happens to be an Android class, so somewhere in a global scope you must have `View View...`, which BTW would *not* be the best thing, so please show the code that clears this up.

Comment: ok wait m editing this...